# Replacement for cap-bound

Tags: linux-kernel, capabilities

We have an old Linux from scratch kernel used in one of our systems, that uses the old cap-bound mechanism (modifying `/proc/sys/kernel/cap-bound`) to restrict the capabilities of the system. This was done at boot-time through the `rc.linux` file.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

We are in the process of updating the kernel, and this functionality no longer exists, and thus far, we have been unable to find how we can emulate this under the new kernel.

If it exists, what is the replacement for the cap-bound mechanism?

Comment: Do you rely just have a kernel, or do you have the whole Operating system. What versions etc?

Comment: My guess is that `init`, should drop the capabilities that are not needed, before forking: now the only way to increase capability is to have an executable file with its permitted set grater than the current effective set.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

```
       P'(ambient)     = (file is privileged) ? 0 : P(ambient)
```

It is possible for a process to gain privileges from its parent.

```
       P'(permitted)   = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) |
                         (F(permitted) & cap_bset) | P'(ambient)
```

It is possible for a process to gain privileges from a file, if its inheritable set has them, or its cap_bset has them.

```
       P'(effective)   = F(effective) ? P'(permitted) : P'(ambient)

       P'(inheritable) = P(inheritable)    [i.e., unchanged]
```

It gets its inherited set from its parents

```
   where:

       P         denotes the value of a thread capability set before the
                 execve(2)

       P'        denotes the value of a thread capability set after the
                 execve(2)

       F         denotes a file capability set

       cap_bset  is the value of the capability bounding set (described
                 below).

   …

   Note that the bounding set masks the file permitted capabilities, but
   not the inheritable capabilities.  If a thread maintains a capability
   in its inheritable set that is not in its bounding set, then it can
   still gain that capability in its permitted set by executing a file
   that has the capability in its inheritable set.
```

You also need to remove from `inheritable` set

Therefore remove privileges from the root process (`init`): remove privileges from `cap_bset`, `inheritable`, `permitted`, and `effective`.